# how can i delete row div dynamically through this code

Tags: javascript

"i update the code" . i am trying to delete row by calling delete function in button (see at create()) in this way:
 my function for creating div:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">

    function create()
    {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newDiv.innerHTML = "<table id='e' border><tr><td><input type='text'><button onclick=del(this.value)</button></td></tr></table>";
//      newDiv.className = 'newClass';
                    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

    }

    function del (e) {
if ('function' === typeof e.remove) {
    return e.remove();
}
return e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript something like this

```
function delete() {
    var element = document.getElementById('elementId');
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

or using jQuery you could just use

```
$('#elementId').remove();
```

Comment: This assumes that the element has an id. Also, in jQuery, it should be ```$('#elementId').remove()```.

Comment: You are correct but it was just an example.   Although, remove will work with any valid jQuery selector it doesn't have to be an id.

Comment: Totally... but in your case, the answer would be clearer if you added the ```#```.

Comment: Er... ```$('#elementId');``` but ```document.getElementById('elementId')```.

Comment: Right again, multi-tasking, updated... and leaving for the day.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below addresses the original question, which had to do with adding/removing elements. In fact, you'll probably be better off going with an out of the box solution to the larger problem. Have a look at [appendGrid](http://appendgrid.apphb.com) and see if it does what you need.

The way to go is to return your new div from the function. Then you can use `div.remove()` to remove it.

```
function create () {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<table border><tr><td><input type='text'></td></tr><button </table>";
    return newDiv;
}
function del (e) {
    if ('function' === typeof e.remove) {
        return e.remove();
    }
    return e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
}
var div = create();
document.body.appendChild(div);
// Some other stuff you want to do...
del(div);
```

Comment: jame shall i place var div = create(); ...  inside del function?

Comment: am doing with the help of button

Comment: Updated to make it a bit more general. I'd need to see what your button is doing to make a more detailed suggestion.

Comment: how "e" is revolving? is it passing through button id or table id?

Comment: It's a generalized function that would let you pass in an element, and delete that element. It doesn't work so well with the inline event handlers you have, though.

Comment: so what shell i do. i am trying to place button for add and delete. add is working but delete is not. shell i pass table id?

Comment: Are you just making one table, or potentially many? The easiest (though not terribly reusable) option is to go with an id. If you do that, though, you need to do something to prevent multiple clicks, since it's bad (technically illegal) to have more than one element on a page with the same id.

Comment: many.its according to demand. for example if i want add more things in row so click on add and if i want to delete then delete.

Comment: Please see my revised answer above. Looking at what you've done so far, you're going to be in for a lot of misery trying to achieve that with pure JS, especially if you need a quick turnaround.

Comment: just tell me how shell i use reference of the row, if i want to delete particular row. as u have suggested me a reference variable in delete function.

Comment: It won't work with the application structure you're setting up. To preserve references, you'll need to use event listeners (instead of the inline event handler you're using), and will need to figure out which div to delete when the button is clicked. It's just not a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either save a reference to `newDiv` or set `newDiv.id` before the end of `create()`, then you can either:
    `newDiv.parentNode.removeChild(newDiv);`
or:
    `document.getElementById(newDiv.id).parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(newDiv.id));`

I would think saving the reference is preferable, but I don't know if that will fit with the rest of your code.  I'm not sure the suggestion James provided will work, because as I understand it, JS doesn't allow HTML elements to commit suicide, only infanticide.

Comment: Tested it in Chrome and it seems to running just fine there.

Comment: jQuery DOES allow it though, so Jonathan's solution should be fine.

Comment: Fair enough, Chrome may have implemented a shortcut.  Just be careful though, it's not in [the spec](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) so some browsers may not support it.

Comment: w3schools is hardly an authority on the (any) subject. However, ```remove``` is, in fact experimental: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove Updating my answer accordingly.